# Euler-Lagrange equations for $p$-Harmonic vector fields

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, p-laplace

Harmonic vector fields are critical points of Dirichlet energy function on the set of all unit vector fields on $M$, which is defined as follows:

$$E(X):=\frac{1}{2}\int_M\|dX\|^2\mathrm{dVol_g}\qquad X: (M,g)\to (TM,g_s), \|X\|=1.$$

Where it's Euler-Lagrange equation satisfies the following:
$$\bar{\Delta}X=\lambda X,\quad \lambda\in C^\infty(M)$$
where $\bar{\Delta}$ denote rough Laplacian.

**$p$-Harmonic vector field:** If we use $p$-energy function instead of Dirichlet energy function:
$$E_p(X):=\frac{1}{p}\int_M\|\mathrm{d}X\|^p\mathrm{dVol_g},\qquad X: (M,g)\to (TM,g_s),$$
The Euler-Lagrange equation of $E_p(.)$ in all vector fields (not in unit case) is as follows ([for function case see this paper](https://lup.lub.lu.se/search/publication/8947d702-7e15-4448-a5cd-700676847aeb)):
$$\|dX\|^{p-2}\left(\tau(X) + dX\left(\mathrm{grad}(\log \|dX\|^{p-2})\right)\right) =0.$$
where $\tau(X)=\mathrm{div}(dX)$ called tension field of $X$.

My questions are :

**Question 1:** What is the Euler-Lagrange of $E_p(.)$ on the set of all unit vector fields on $M$?

**Question 2:** Can one hope to get statements which is generalized and new (not same to exactly) 2-harmonic (harmonic vector field) case?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't Question 1 just Lagrange multipliers? Also, what do you mean by a tension field of $X$? Is it not just $\overline\Delta X$? How do you understand the term involving $dX$? Is $dX$ supposed to be the antisymmetrized derivative for just the covariant derivative of $X$ w.r.t. $g$?

Comment: Tension field is just an equivalent equation to Euler-Lagrange equation and here I don't know what is it exactly. $dX: TM\to TTM$ is derivation of vector field $X$.

Comment: Just to check my understanding, is it the case that $\| dX\|^2 = n + \|\nabla X\|^2$? Imposing that you are keeping variations within the sphere bundle, and denoting by the infinitesimal variation $V$, you have that $\langle X, V\rangle = 0$, which means that $\| d (X + V)\|^2 = n + \|\nabla (X+V)\|^2$ which to linear order gives $n + \|\nabla X\|^2 + 2 \langle \nabla X, \nabla V\rangle$. This would imply that for the $p$ case you have the ELE being

Comment: $$ \mathrm{div}_g \cdot \left[ (n + \|\nabla X\|^2)^{p/2 - 1} \nabla X \right] = \lambda X $$ since the integral of the inner product of the left hand side against any vector field orthogonal to $X$ must be 0. The constant $\lambda$ can also be computed using that $X$ is of unit norm as $$ \lambda = - (n + |\nabla X\|^2)^{p/2 - 1} \|\nabla X\|^2 $$ (These are all predicate in my assumption that $\|dX\|^2 = n + \|\nabla X\|^2$ is correct.)

Comment: Yes, I think your assumption $\|dX\|^2 = n + \|\nabla X\|^2$ is correct.